# extending jqueryUI tooltip widget that has already been extended

Tags: jquery, widget, extend

We have already extended the jquery ui tooltip to a custom widget. We need to extend this even further without touching the custom widget. I am having difficulty getting this to work. Please help.

```
(function ($) {
var extensionMethods = {
        open: function () {
            var childElem = target.children('img');
                if (childElem.length) {
                    childElem.data('alt', childElem.attr('alt'));
                    childElem.removeAttr('alt');                
                }
            $ui.tooltip.prototype.open.apply(this, arguments);
            console.log("extension open works!");
        },
        close: function () {
            var childElem = target.children('img');
                if (childElem.data('alt')) {
                    childElem.attr('alt', childElem.data('alt'));
                }
            $ui.tooltip.prototype.close.apply(this, arguments);
            console.log("extension close works!");
        },        
    }

    var methods = $.extend(true, {}, $.ui.tooltip.prototype, extensionMethods);
    $.widget('my.customtooltip', methods);


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend it in the same way, as the original widget, all you need is a constructor of custom widget:

```
// extend basic widget
var myTooltipWidget = $.widget('myTooltipWidget', $.ui.tooltip, {
    // widget code here
});

// extend custom widget
var myExtendedTooltipWidget = $.widget('myExtendedTooltipWidget', myTooltipWidget, {
    // widget code here
});
```